# auto-suggest stopped working on my notebook

Tags: pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks

After switching between clusters (detach/attach), the auto-suggest feature stopped working for me on the current notebook I work on and I can't get auto-completion when I type the TAB key after a period, I get: '*no suggestions*'.

I tried to delete cookies, but it didn't help.

Any idea why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would you mind providing the code or snipper where it stopped working?

Comment: no specific code, it's just stopped working, no auto-suggest

Comment: Does `CTRL+SPACE` work?

Comment: no, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that cluster is attached, cluster must be started and a query run for autocomplete to be working.